# Extract a number from an amount from a String

Tags: java, regex

I have below method which I use to extract amount from a string.

`strAmountString = "$272.94/mo for 24 months Regular Price -$336.9"`

```
public static String fnAmountFromString(String strAmountString) {
    String strOutput = "";

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\$(-?\\d+.\\d+)?.*");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(strAmountString);

    while(mat.find())
        strOutput = mat.group(1);

    return strOutput;
}
```

Now I have to extract string `272.94` from the string and above function works fine.

But when I have to extract `272.94` from String `strAmountString = "272.94"`, gives me a null.

Also I have to extract the amount `-336.9` from `string strAmountString = "$272.94/mo for 24 months Regular Price -$336.9"`

Comment: The first part `String strAmountString = "272.94"` is because your `String` doesn't meet the requirements of the regular expression `"\\$(-?\\d+.\\d+)?.*"`

Comment: Is this just an exercise to practice RegEx? Or are you actually tring to get these values? If it's not an exercise then regex is probably not the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Your first issue, with trying to use `272.94`, is related to the requirements of your regular expression, the fact that there is a requirement for the `String` to be lead by a `$`

You could make `$` part of an optional group, for example `((\\$)?\\d+.\\d+)`, which will match both `272.94` and `$272.94`, but won't match `-$336.9` directly, it will match `$336.9` though.

So, working off your example, you could use `((-)?(\\$)?\\d+.\\d+)` which will now match `-$336.9` as well...

Personally, I might use `((-)?(\\$)?(-)?\\d+.\\d+)`, which will match `-$336.9`, `$-336.9`, `-336.9` and `336.9`

The next step would be try remove `$` from the result, yes, you could try using another regular expression, but to be honest, `String#replaceAll` would be easier...

Note- My regular expression knowledge is pretty basic, so there might be simpler soltion

**Updated with example**

```
String value = "$272.94/mo for 24 months Regular Price -$336.9";
String regExp = "((-)?(\\$)?(-)?\\d+.\\d+)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regExp);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(value);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Which outputs...

```
$272.94
-$336.9
```

Comment: It might just be me but having trouble with the expression: http://regexr.com?38fpr

Comment: @KevinBowersox Updated with an example and I used http://regexpal.com/ as basic tester...

Comment: @KevinBowersox Also remove the escaped \, Java requires these. Using  http://regexr.com?38fpu, you would need to use `((-)?(\$)?(-)?\d+.\d+)` instead, otherwise the splashes become literals

Answer (score 0):

The following reg ex will get you your two groups (as group 1 and group 3)

```
(\\$\\d+\\.\\d+)(.*)?(\\-?\\$\\d+\\.\\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make the dollar sign in your Pattern optional - or in other words, it needs to exist 0 or more times. Use the `*` qualifier.

Second, if you're sure that the dollar amount will always be at the beginning of the string, you can use the `^` boundary matcher, which indicates the beginning of the line.

Similarly, if you're sure that the final dollar amount will always be at the end of the line, you can use the `$` boundary matcher.

See more details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Test your patterns here: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html